# Can I disable the "Alt+Shift" shortcut to change language in windows 8.1 (or Windows 10)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1, input-languages

I'm using windows 8.1 with multiple languages. The new pretty shortcut <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> will pop up a pretty looking selection on the right.

Now, hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> (left ones) will also change the language.

This 2nd option clashes with some of my other shortcuts (mainly sublime text), and I can't find where/how to disable it. I remember it was possible in previous versions of windows where you could select the shortcut for changing languages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try something like `Autohotkey`

Comment: @Ramhound to do what? I've used it to create hot keys for things, but wouldn't the default windows take precedence over it?

Comment: Autohotkey can allow you to override shortcuts.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Good golly ... spent too much time on it, but found it eventually.

It's hidding in:
Clock,Language, ande Region -> Language -> Advanced Settings -> Change language bar hot keys.
(the last is in the "switching input methods").

Here's a [website with screenshots](http://winaero.com/blog/configuring-language-settings-in-windows-8/) .

Once done, you can change or disable it. (which made me realize i have another program that was trying (yet failing) to use those shortcuts :) ).

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 the path is slightly different, _Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings_

Comment: original question was for 8.1 :) . I guess your comment will help people with ... more modern windows ...

Comment: You solved this annoying feature... when programming I often use ALT and Shift key... so I often switched language by mistake. Thanks!!!!

Comment: @MatteoConta You're welcome. Being bilingual or multilingual can be a bit of a pain sometimes ;) .Glad it helped.

Comment: I can't find the path described by @JohnC. I think Windows 10 has changed its location.

Comment: @Andre-Soares, look at Andrew Ward's answer to this question, I verified that his sequence works on my Windows 10, build 17134.407. In summary, Windows Settings (formerly Control Panel) > Time & Language > Region & language > Advanced keyboard settings > Language bar options > Advanced Key Settings > Change Key Sequence. Way too long a sequence.

Comment: I found the path. But even with all shortcuts disabled, Win+Space still shows the input selection popup.

Comment: Couldn't navigate to it so I searched for `advanced keyboard settings`

Answer (score 140):

## Windows 10 / Windows 11

**March, 2024**

> [This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/698037/can-i-disable-the-altshift-shortcut-to-change-language-in-windows-8-1-or-win/1385457?noredirect=1#comment2414640_1385457) reports solution works on Windows 2004 also.

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `Advanced keyboard settings` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   [image: Windows Search for 'Advanced Keyboard Settings']
2. **Input language hot keys** (left)
   [image: Select 'Input language hot keys']
3. **Change Key Sequence...** (for "Between input languages")
   [image: Select "Advanced Key Settings" tab, and press "Change Key Sequence"]
4. **Set to "Not Assigned"** 
   [image]

**If you upvote this, I'll update the subtitle date so that we know it still works.**

*(Thanks @bugybunny, @Bassie-c, and @skajfes for improvements.)*

Comment: Confirmed working in february 2019.

Comment: I am on 1809 and connected to a domain and in the settings I had `Region & language` split up. I had to click on `Language`, `Spelling, typing & keyboard settings` on the right (under Related settings) then scroll to the bottom and then on `Advanced keyboard settings`. The rest is the same
Edit: just noticed that you can also press Win key and search for “Typing settings” and then find `Advanced keyboard settings` at the bottom.

Comment: Still working!!

Comment: I don't have the Advanced Keyboard Settings there on screenshot 4 (Windows 10 Pro 1903)

Comment: Ah, I found were it is. I basicly followed @bugybunny 's road I see now. But a quicker way would be to go to `Devices` -> `Typing` and than the `Advanced keyboard settings` are on the bottom.

Comment: @Bassie-c good call. I'll work on updating this.

Comment: Tap `Windows key` > type `settings`, press `enter` > choose `Devices` > choose `Typing` (left panel) > choose `Advanced keyboard settings` (text link near bottom) > choose `Language bar options` (link) > go to `Advanced Key Settings` tab > select Action `Between input languages` > Click `Change Key Sequence...` > `Not Assigned` (or as preferred) > `OK`

Comment: I find search much simpler to use since the settings get moved around much lately. Search for `Advanced keyboard settings` in the start menu. From there click on `Input language hotkeys` which brings you to step 7 described above.

Comment: @skajfes Nice find. Thanks for sharing. I'll update this ASAP.

Comment: It seems they've upgraded the behaviour at some point between Dec 2019 and May 2020, where sometimes Windows 10 loaded multiple inputs for the same language (e.g. Spanish (International) and also Spanish (Spain)) but showing them without distinction in the language popup, and there was no way to remove one of them. Now is possible. Also, if you press SHIFT+ALT instead of ALT+SHIFT the popup doesn't show up

Comment: Hey folks, I understand this can be disabled, but I'm bilingual and really need to switch back and forth constantly... is there any way to assign a DIFFERENT key combination? Using ALT+SHIFT is a pain, since when developing it conflicts with many editor shortcuts.

Comment: @JoseCifuentes I don't know. My advice is to look around the various StackExchange sites, and if there's nothing already answering your question, ask that question as its own question. It's unlikely you'll find an answer here for that question. If you do find an answer elsewhere, or ask your own question, and you're feeling generous, perhaps come back here to leave a comment with a link to that thread. I can even update my answer to help redirect people there.

Comment: @ReedDunkle I actually found a way! In W10 open "Advanced Keyboard Settings" (search on Start Menu), click "Language bar options", click tab "Advanced Key Settings", then you can assign a different key sequence to each of "To English" and "To Spanish" individually. For example, I am using "Left Alt + Shift + 9" for English, and "Left Alt + Shift + 8" for Spanish. No conflicts and works nice.

Comment: thanks this works for windows 2004. They removed language from control panel

Comment: After years of bothering with accidental language swapping in Windows, I finally disabled this too. Thanks for one problem less in my life. 

Comment: Thank you! Confirmed working in Win10 21H2.

Comment: Also works for Windows 11 - thanks!

Answer (score 52):

Under Windows 10, another lazier way to achieve the same goal is to run the following command line.

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL input.dll,,{C07337D3-DB2C-4D0B-9A93-B722A6C106E2}{HOTKEYS}
```

Comment: That was the only working way for me to open that dialog. Thank you very much!

Comment: This command made my day. I gave up trying to find the dialog in the control panel. Its just complete rubbish, at this point.

Comment: Fantastic, for win 2019 server this was the only way to resolve! Thank You much!

Comment: Should be marked as answer. It is difficult that Microsoft is moving (and removing) ui elements.

Comment: Worked on my company Laptop where the "Input language hot keys" option was (intentionally or accidentally) disabled, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

The option seems to have moved yet again for the latest Windows 10 update, at least for me (I no longer have a "Language" icon in the Control Panel).

Open the Region & Language settings applet.

Then "Advanced keyboard settings" in Related settings on the right.

Then "Language bar options".

The "Text Services and Input Languages" dialog will appear.  Select the "Advanced Key Settings" tab and you'll be shown a Key Sequence list for changing between input languages.

Comment: Hmmm... i still have it no mine. But maybe there's an update coming. Do you have multiple languages set up on your machine ? (I've updated the question title since it seems to be so popular it moved to Win 10 :) ) Cheers.

Comment: I have three keyboard languages installed, currently using English (USA) as language, but different keyboard layout. I went to Settings App->Time & Language->Language->Spelling, typing & keyboard settings (in related settings)->Advanced keyboard settings->Language bar options->Advanced key settings and then set Unassigned in key sequence for the option "Between input languages".

Comment: no longer working

Answer (score 3):

The location has changed in Windows 11.

[image]

Once there, the dialogs are the same as in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Create and import a REG file:

`Disable keyboard language toggle.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Toggle]
"Language HotKey"="3"
"Layout HotKey"="3"

[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Toggle]
"Language HotKey"="3"
"Layout HotKey"="3"
```

Answer (score -1):

On windows 10 I figured it out:

in the windows taskbar search for **language settings**

click on **choose an input method to always choose as default** *(at the bottom)*

**language bar options**

**advanced key settings tab**

select **between input languages** and press the button **change key sequence**

press both radio buttons on "**not assigned** and press ok

**then press apply**