# Clicking on mouse wheel button switches language

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse-wheel, language-bar

I have two languages installed on my `Windows 8.1 OS`: English and Hebrew.

Recently I've started to use mouse middle click to open a link in `Chrome` in a new tab, and then I noticed that when I do that, it switches the `language bar` from English to Hebrew and vice versa.

I though that this is some kind of [hot key](https://superuser.com/a/698595/591675) defined to switch between languages, but couldn't see such thing:

[image: Change language bar hot key wizard screenshot]

I looked in the mouse and language settings in the `Control Panel` and couldn't find anything related. Google also didn't give me useful information either.

I don't know if it's related but I use an external mouse connected to my `Lenovo ThinkPad T420` laptop.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any third party software for mouse, keyboard? Does it happen if you disable the hotkey for language switching?

Comment: No for the first question. Do you mean disable all the hot keys? (Left Alt + Shift)

Comment: Yes, I meant to disable the hotkey for language switching from the screenshot you provided. Just to see if it uses that setting when you middle click the mouse.

Comment: If I disable it, then it stops switching on mouse wheel clicking. But I do want to switch using Left Alt + Shift.

Comment: Try to change it to some other key combination to check if the wheel click will change it or not. If not then (somehow) your wheel click simulates a Left Alt + Shift. Strange. Do you have an additional mouse to see if it will behave the same? Do not unplug the first, leave both connected and check.

Comment: Looks indeed like my wheel click simulates a Left Alt + Shift. I tried with another mouse- the same behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39613/discussion-between-zina-and-user3114639).