# Windows 10, 1909 build, causes overlay in game on language change (shift + alt)

Tags: windows, windows-10, input-languages, windows-10-v1909

When I'm in the game and press shift + alt (I use alt for voice chant, and shift fir sprint) it shows language change overlay on top of a game. I'm perfectly ok for language change, but overlay makes it inconvenient

[image]

Comment: An answer to this question [Alt + Shift to change language no longer working after upgrade to Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949712/alt-shift-to-change-language-no-longer-working-after-upgrade-to-windows-10) contains instructions to change the shortcut to display this overlay.  You can also remove unused keyboard layouts and the shortcut will no longer display the overlay.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I disable the "Alt+Shift" shortcut to change language in windows 8.1 (or Windows 10)?](https://superuser.com/questions/698037/can-i-disable-the-altshift-shortcut-to-change-language-in-windows-8-1-or-win)

Comment: Probably easiest in this case to remove or hide the notification.  It cannot be moved if you choose to keep the notification

Comment: No, sorry guys, my question was not clear, but anyway, I've found a way to hide that overlay

Comment: @cleverketchup mind sharing what you found to hide the overlay?

Answer (score 2):

Reposted from the question author's original answer.

1. In Windows 10 click in the search box at the bottom left of your screen and search for "Advanced keyboard settings".

   [image: Advanced keyboard settings]
2. Select *Input language hot keys* -> *Language Bar* tab, *Language Bar* section -> click *Hidden* radio button.

   [image]

Comment: just heads up. As example, when swapping language with Alt+Shift, if you hold down Alt and click Shift without releasing Alt Language bar appears anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: https://github.com/StormExecute/InputSwitcherX

1. Download python 3 - https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. Run installation and check "add python to PATH" (you can select custom installation and uncheck other unnecessary stuff like IDE etc.).
3. Reboot
4. Download package from github - "Code" > "Download zip" and unpack it.
5. Run command line as administrator and go to package, for example: "cd C:\InputSwitcherX-master"
6. Run "python usePatch.py"

Worked for me!

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: @Toto I'm answering the topic question.  This patch removes shortcut for language switch bar.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.